# Passing Param to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

So I have users mark favorite posts. I'm trying to adjust the index to show only there favorite posts.

My index controller looks like this

```
def index
  require 'soundcloud'
  @streamid = '?client_id=7e24fb69b20b922b683870511ae8d2d1'
  @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => '7e24fb69b20b922b683870511ae8d2d1')
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  elsif params[:genre]
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:genre]).order("created_at DESC")
  elsif params[:favorites]
    @posts = Post.first
  else
    @posts = Post.reorder('votes desc').find_with_reputation(:votes, :all).first(10)
  end
end
```

My link_to button looks like this

```
<li><%= link_to ("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i> My Favorites").html_safe, root_path(:param => :favorites) %></li>
```

The url changes to

> http://localhost:3000/?param=favorites

But the page doesn't update to the @posts variable in the controller.

What do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need two steps:

1. change your parameter in view:

   `<li><%= link_to ("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i> My Favorites").html_safe, root_path(:favorites => 1) %></li>`

   It will generate a link to `http://localhost:3000/?favorites=1`
2. In your controller, check the parameter 'favorites' as a string. Replace the line

   `elsif params[:favorites]`

   with

   `elsif params[:favorites].present? and params[:favorites].to_s == '1'`

Comment: Awesome Yang! Thanks for the help. Will mark as correct after 3 min timer goes away.